# Debugging JS and Node.js In Eclipse 2022

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

Does anyone know of a good guide to debugging a JavaScript file/project using Node.js while using Eclipse 2022? I've seen a few articles but they all relate to previous versions of Eclipse and no longer seem applicable or work.

I can run a simple hello-world.js program at command-line [ node --inspect-brk hello-world.js] and then interact with Chrome's node.js debug tool [chrome://inspect/] but curious if this can all be done within Eclipse.

Comment: Where did you get stuck using [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper)? Please show your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For example; how is the node.js runtime attached in the Debug/Run time configurations dialogs? As my question states, I was looking for a detailed example/tutorial/explanation of using js/nodejs/eclipse-2022. Thus, not really a case of "show your code".

Comment: Have you watched the videos that are listed on the website? There is not much documentation. Maybe you can contribute what you find out. Some information can be discovered from the JUnit tests.

Comment: And where would the Eclipse JS/NodeJS Debugging videos be located?

Comment: See https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper#-media-library - first and third videos. Both are a bit outdated. So it would be great if you could contribute some documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link but videos 1 and 3 are for html files and not NodeJS. If you step through the short video 3 you'll see that a .html file has to be pointed to and not a NodeJS .js file. etc etc etc.

Comment: In order to "you could contribute some documentation", one would first have to know what the designed method of using NodeJS in Eclipse is, which is the whole point of this post. With no Help button on the "Debug Configurations" and other dialogs, users are left wondering how to use this. As usual with a great deal of software - tremendous effort injected into developing it and zero effort into explaining how it works.

Comment: In _Run > Debug Configurations..._ you created a _Node.js application_ debug configuration, right? Or where exactly did you get stuck?